# Placing an if statement directly inside a React component

Tags: reactjs

Is it bad practice to place an if statement directly inside a React component:

```js
const SomeComponent = props => { if (something) {} return (); }
```

?

Because I am familiar with:

```js
const SomeComponent = props => { someHandler() { if (something) {} } return (); }
```

if statement being inside some function like a handler.

Is it OK to place an if statement directly inside a component?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that, no performance impact, no error. A (functional) React component is basically a function, so you are free to write some logic in it.